# A question about the word "contain" in the context of set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It is my understanding that sets are said to contain their elements but also a set is said to contain its subsets. However, I feel like this might lead to a confusion since while a set contains its subsets, its subsets are not necessarily elements of it. It seems to me the word "contain" must be restricted to only one of these meanings and there must be another word for the other.

Am I missing something here or is this supposed to be understood from the given context?

Comment: Not use it... The $\in$ relation is the [relation between an *element* $e$ and a *set* $S$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory#Basic_concepts_and_notation) and we say that element $e$ belongs to set $S$: $e \in S$.

Comment: It is a different relation wrt the [*subset* relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory#Basic_concepts_and_notation): $\subseteq$ that applies to *sets*: $S_1 \subseteq S$ and we say taht set $S_1$ is a subset of set $S$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I understand that those two are different relations but I think my question is more about the usage of the word "contain" in this context. Are you saying that one should simply avoid using the word and I am right that such an ambiguity occurs? If that's the case then there is no problem but I wanted to see if I was missing a certain subtlety or anything.

Comment: Yes. See e.g. Enderton's [Set Theory](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Elements_of_Set_Theory/DOnkAH-I02sC), page 1: "we write '$t \in A$' to say that $t$ is a *member* of $A$" and see page 3: "If $A \subseteq B$, then we also say that $A$ is *included* in $B$." That's all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very possible that some authors have used "contain" to refer to the element relation, and others to refer to the subset relation.

In either case, yes, the word "contain" is more colloquial. In context, it's often clear what is meant by the word "contain," but if you wanted to be extra careful you would avoid using the word altogether.